# Micro USB B Pick-n-Place info

Tags: pcb, usb, altium, pcb-assembly

Altium Designer exports Pick-n-Place coordinates for a micro USB-B connector as geometric center of signal layers (top and bottom) area (other layers do not affect the coordinates) (a yellow mark on the picture). But the actual coordinates of the center of the connector are different (a blue mark on the picture). Should I fix the coordinates manually after export from Altium or this is correct coordinates, and a manufacturer will figure it out.

Also, which orientation is considered as zero orientation for the micro USB-B connector? I just copy footprint from datasheets (where the connector looks down), but in the tape/reel he looks to the right. So I'm nor sure which orientation is zero-orientation.

[image]

Comment: The manufacturer will figure it out (that's part of what you're paying for with the setup fees) but I'm still interested in what the correct thing to do is here. Does Altium always pick the centroid of the conductors no matter where you place the origin in the PcbLib?

Comment: @pericynthion Tried to change origin in PcbLib, it doesn't affect on "Mid-X, Mid-Y" coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altium (by default) exports both coordinates to the PnP file. "Mid-X, Mid-Y" (yellow coordinate system) and "Ref-X, Ref-Y" (blue coordinate system). But, from my experience, it doesn't really matter, because the operator needs to set up the pick up point and placing point manually for all the "unusual/not rectangular" parts.
And, if you have both coordinates in PnP file, they can use the one that they prefer.

When it comes to rotation, if you can, try to use the one that you see on the "tape and reel" drawing in the datasheet. On all the machines I worked with, this was considered the "zero rotation" (tape going "up" and sprocket holes on left):

[image: Tape rotation]